# How to access array of char pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am reading from a text file set of words into an array of char pointers, after reading how to display each word separately using printf?

Code Snippet :

```
FILE *ptr_file;
char *word[1000];
int wordCount=0;

ptr_file = fopen("C:\\c_read_test.txt","r");

while(fscanf(ptr_file,"%s", word) == 1)  //scans every word in the text file
 wordCount++;
```

Comment: What are `word1` and `wordCount`?

Comment: You cannot read a "*set of words into an array of char pointers*".

Comment: @alk The code which I am trying to get is similar to below array:
`code`
char *ptr[] = {
"first word",
"second word",
"third word"
}
`code`

Comment: The problem in my above snippet was all the words were getting stored at only one place at first Pointer : word i.e. &word[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could do it. The limit for words is now 1000, and words can't be longer than 50 char.

```
FILE *ptr_file;
char word[1000][50]
int wordCount=0;

ptr_file = fopen("C:\\c_read_test.txt","r");

while(fscanf(ptr_file,"%s", word[wordCount]) == 1) { //scans every word in the text file
    printf("%s\n", word[wordCount++]);
    if(wordCount >= 1000) break;
}
```

But this is not how I would do it, if c++ is an option. I would use std and a vector or list of strings.

Comment: Thanks, @JoriO I now have one challenge to find out the distinct words from this "word" pointer array. Can you help how to compare contents of 2 pointers?

Comment: In this case, i also tried *word[index1] == *word[index2] and it worked as successful comparison:-)

Comment: @ks_baba no, it was pointers comparison as integer addresses. You have to compare each pair of characters in both strings to be sure they are equal. That is what `strcmp` do.

Answer (score 0):

```
char word[200][50];
int wordcount=0;
while(fscanf(ptr_file,"%s",word[wordcount])==1)
{
 wordcoutn++;
} 
int i=0;
while(i<=wordcount)
printf(word[i]);
```

Comment: That is how to print them, but I think the asker wants the words to be stored in an array.

Comment: char word[200][50];// hope there is only less than 200words
int wordcount=0;
fscanf(ptr_file,"%s",word[wordcount]);

Comment: Then your solution saves all words to the space reserved for the first one.

Comment: every time you reading a word the word count is incrementing. so each word using sperate space

Comment: Check what you have written before to save edits. There are no `wordcoutn` defined and infinite cycle at the end.